# how to separate Display name fultter google fire base authentication

Tags: firebase, flutter

I have google sign in authentication and i need name and surname of an user and put into my firebase database, the problem is that display name (obtained by google) is composed by name and surname togheter, so i need to separate them. The problem is that i can have in my application compound Names, i give u some example:

- Pier Paolo Del Greco (first 2 words are the name, the others surname)
- Mario Giordano (first name, second surname)
- Mario Di Giordano (first name, second and third surname)
- Mario Del greco (same of the last example)
- Pio Paolo Sorrento (first and second are the name, last surname)

There is an option of displayname, that split automatically name and surname? Or have you any idea for an alghoritm that solve this issue?

My code (Works only for classic name and surname each with 1 word)

```
class GoogleSignInProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  GoogleSignInAccount? _user;
  GoogleSignInAccount get user => _user!;

  Future googleLogin() async {
    final googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    if (googleUser == null) return;
    _user = googleUser;

    print(_user?.email);
    final names = _user?.displayName!.split(' ');
    final nome = names![0];
    final cognome = names[1];
    final googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

    final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );

    var firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    UserSetup(uid: firebaseUser!.uid).updateUserData(nome, cognome);
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);

    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: You can split based on the email, most common email format is name.surname@gmail.com, maybe you can write an algoritm based on that?

Comment: I don't think so. Emails often have got format as surname.name, so there will be a problem

Comment: yes but you still have the name and surname separated by the dot ...

Comment: Hey, did you ever find a good solution to this? I'd like to implement something similar